# Echo the variable in .bat file from a text file

Tags: windows, variables, batch-file, command-line

Good Day, I'm still new in DOS Commands, I want to if still possible. I have a `.bat` that I want to call a value from a text file. What I mean I'm doing a `.bat` file (generic) that will use by normal user by changing only the value from the text file.

Example:

I have this command in my bat file: (It's just an example)

```
@ECHO OFF 
echo First Name:
echo Kobe
echo LastName:
echo Bryant
pause
```

Instead of editing the `.bat` file or setting the variable on `.bat` file. I want to create a  `set.txt` that will hold the variables.

Example:

**set.txt**

```
FirstName=Kobe
LastName=Bryant
```

So the `.bat` file will be generic/flexible. No need to change.

**run.bat**

```
echo First Name:
echo $FirstName
echo Last Name:
echo $LastName
```

Any tips on how I will do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code would make the output fully dynamic, in case you don't even know the names of the variables.

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

for /f "delims== tokens=1*" %%A in (set.txt) do (
  set "%%A=%%B"
  echo %%A:
  echo %%B
)
```

If your file name includes spaces or poison characters like `&` or `^`, then you would want to quote the filename, in which case you would need to add the `usebackq` option.

```
for /f "usebackq delims== tokens=1*" %%A in ("name with space.txt") do ...
```

Comment: Well explained. Thank you very much sir

Comment: Its very dynamic due to it's look like it tell the variable by sequence?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure in the set.txt there are no spaces surrounding the `=` sign:

```
@echo off
for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("set.txt") do (
  set "%%#"
)
echo First Name:
echo %FirstName%
echo Last name:
echo %LastName%
```

Comment: Thank you sir very much sir

Answer (score 1):

```
For /f "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%A in (file.txt) do Echo %A %B
```

Is  how to. See `for /?`.